# How do you debug a .dpk using delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have a `.dpk` project I'd like to debug.

I tried just including the source and setting a breakpoint in a C++Builder application, but it does not break.  So I'm now in Delphi on another machine, with the package which I installed. I setup a Delphi app that uses the component from the package.

I load the `.dpk` project, setup `run/parameters` to run the other app.  I set a breakpoint, run the `.dpk`, but the breakpoint doesn't break.

What is the correct way to debug / step through a `.dpk` project?

Comment: Well it looks like in Delphi I can do it the way I tried in C++Builder and it works so there must be a difference there.

Comment: You can't load/run a `.dpk` project in C++Builder, only in Delphi. You can add Delphi `.pas` files to a C++Builder `.bpk`/`.cbproj` project, though. Did you compile the `.dpk` with debugging symbols enabled? How about the app project? Sounds like maybe you are not doing that.

Comment: Add all sources to your project. Create the component at run time.  and go from there.